# Restricting iOS camera to single app only

Tags: ios, camera

I have a requirement to disable the iPad camera and only make it accessible from within a single in-house app.

I've used Apple Configurator to install a configuration profile that disables the camera. The only option I see is to disable it globally. When I do this, the camera is unavailable in the app. I don't see an option to create something like a whitelist to only allow certain apps to access the camera.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `result = haveCake + andEatItToo`

Comment: How is this helpful? Can someone offer something useful or insightful?

Comment: Pretty sure that what @RobertHarvey is saying is that what you want isn't something you can do.

Comment: @user2744169: I have the solution for this problem. However, it's company IP, so can't share it. In the case, if your are ok to use 3rd party app (vs writing it on your own), please contact me (my email is in my profile). P.S. Sorry, SO guys, I know, it's bad practice to write such self-advertising comments

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it. However, it has some limitation.

Let say you have a MDM server which can install and remove configuration profile. This server can send a configuration profile to enable and disable camera.

Your appliation should communicate with MDM server and let it know what it's started and stopped. MDM server will remove camera restriction when app is started and install config profile again when it's stopped.

Several caveats:

- Obviously it works only if you are online
- There will be some time lag